# Not able to fetch complete values from table

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, join

I have 3 tables as shown below

```
table1
id  name contactno
1    A     1111
```

table2

```
id  fullname   contactno
1     B          2222
```

table3

```
id   table1_id    table2_id
1      1            1
```

I want to fetch the id of table1 and table2 from table3 and according to the fetched id, I want to fetch the data from their respective tables. For this, I am using the following query

```
$query = $this->db->select('*')
  ->from('table3')
  ->join('table1', 'table1.id = table3.table1_id', 'inner')
  ->join('table2', 'table2.id = table3.table2_id', 'inner')
  ->get();
```

I am getting the desired result in the following array

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 1
            [name] => A
            [fullname] => B
            [contactno] => 2222
        )
)
```

As you can see the contact number of only 1 table is being fetched, whereas I want that the contact number of both the tables should be shown in the array
Can anyone please tell how to do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
$query = $this->db->select('table1.id,table1.name,table2.fullname,table1.contactno as con1,table2.contactno as con2')
->from('table3')
->join('table1', 'table1.id = table3.table1_id', 'inner')
->join('table2', 'table2.id = table3.table2_id', 'inner')
->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$query = $this->db->select('*')
  ->from('table3')
  ->join('table1', 'table1.id = table3.table1_id', 'left')
  ->join('table2', 'table2.id = table3.table2_id', 'left')
  ->get();
```